# Java Web Start Application Run from HTTPS Server Blocked By Java Security

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I am attempting to run a Java Web Start application from within a web application running on a HTTPS Tomcat server. The JNLP is generated dynamically by a servlet within the web app. I'm getting an "Application Blocked by Java Security" message, even though I've added the website to the Exception list in the Java Control Panel. The JWS application is currently built using Java 1.7 but the web application is built with 1.8; could that be the issue?

Comment: No more details about exception hidden under a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem stemmed from a name change made for the server in question, as the codebase I was using to build my application referred to the old server name...